# How do I define a java method in a class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I really hope someone can help me, as I've been sitting and looking at this problem for hours and I think it's just a detail that is missing...but not sure.

I have defined a class Triangle which is supposed to take 3 (x,y) coordinates and from it, calculate sidelengths, corners and area.  The class looks like this:

```
   public class Triangle {
        private double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        double sideA, sideB, sideC;
        private double angleA, angleB, angleC;

        public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, 
            double y2, double x3, double y3) {
        }

        public double getSideA() {
            return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)+Math.pow((y3-y2),2)));
        }
    }
```

Now I want to call my getSideA method in my Interaction class and.  I have defined my coordinate variables and they get their values from scan method.  I have also defined a variable sideA, that I want to get the value from my getSideA method.  This is how I have done it:

```
Triangle userTriangle = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);   

 userTriangle.getSideA = sideA;
```

When I try to compile the Interaction class I get the following error code:

```
Interaction.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable getSideA
location: class Triangle
     userTriangle.getSideA = sideA;
                 ^
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong??

Comment: shouldn't you be sayin userTriangle.getSideA() - its a method right.

Comment: If you have defined a variable x, and you want to assign 5 to it, do you use `5 = x;`?

Answer (score 5):

Assignment & function invocation are being performed **incorrectly**.

```
sideA =  userTriangle.getSideA();
                               ^parens necessary when calling function

    <---------- (value assigned from right to left)
```

**Assignment occurs from right to left.**

---

Also, private variables in your class are **not being set**. You won't end up with the expected result. Set the instance variables **within** the constructor, using

```
this.<pvt_var> = value_passed_to_constructor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2` and `y3` are variables and have been assigned values you should do this:

```
Triangle userTriangle = new Triangle(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3); 
double sideA = userTriangle.getSideA();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `getSideA` is a function, so you can't just call `userTriangle.getSideA`, you need to call `userTriangle.getSideA()`

Either you want to get `sideA`, in which case you should write

```
sideA = userTriangle.getSideA()
```

either you want to set your triangle's `sideA`, in which case you should write a `setSideA()` method and call it like this:

```
userTriangle.setSideA(sideA)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, compilation error becouse should be

```
double sideA = userTriangle.getSideA();
```

also your constructor has problems. It should be something like

```
public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
    {
       this.x1 = x1;
       this.y1 = y1;
       this.x2 = x2;
       this.y2 = y2;
       this.x3 = x3;
       this.y3 = y3;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3 in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
userTriangle.getSideA = sideA;
```

Should be

```
sideA = userTriangle.getSideA();
```

Answer (score 1):

`userTriangle.getSideA = sideA;` is not correct

Try this:

```
double sideA= userTriangle.getSideA();
```

And the constructor should be:

```
public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
    {
       this.x1 = x1;
       this.y1 = y1;
       this.x2 = x2;
       this.y2 = y2;
       this.x3 = x3;
       this.y3 = y3;

    }
```

Comment: Why does the constructor have to have "this.x1 = x1" for each variable?  I mean, I have already assigned values to the variables.  Here's an example:
`code`
System.out.print( "Enter the x-coordinate for the first point, and then press Enter: ");
   while (! scan.hasNextInt())
 {
  garbage = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
 } 
  x1 = scan.nextDouble( );`code`